# Signal handler and local state

Tags: c++, unix, signals

I'm working in C++ on Unix.

Say I have a long running function that does something, for example read stuff from file and parse it. In this function I keep count of the things I read from the file in a local variable `num_read`.

I want to catch CTRL+c in a custom signal handler and print the value of `num_read`.

The only way I can think of is allocating `num_read` on the heap and storing its adress in a global variable that can be accessed by my signal handler. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  There is *no* way of communicating between
a signal handler and the rest of code except by global
variables.

Also, you can only do a very, very limited number of things in
a signal handler.  You cannot use a `<<` on an `std::ostream`,
for example, nor can you call `printf`.  The usual way of
handling signals under Unix is to catch them in a separate
thread.  The alternative (which works for other OS's as well) is
to define a global variable of `sig_atomic_t`, which is set in
the signal handler, and polled in the main loop.  (In your case,
for example, you might poll it every time you update 
`num_read`.)

Comment: Or, for unix people who hate threads (me!), the more traditional way of handling signals is with a self-pipe... Much nicer! Guarantees as well that a select() loop gets woken up (there are piles of race conditions with the global flag method for waking up a wait() loop, requiring some sigsuspend/sigprocmask acrobatics). I'd always recommend a self-pipe for its portability, robustness, and total avoidance of all the subtle issues.

Comment: @NicholasWilson I agree that threads are often abused, but they do have their use.  For what the OP is trying to do, the `sig_atomic_t` flag is largely sufficient, and it _is_ portable, even to non-Unix systems.  And when you need to do something complicated, and there are no convenient places to poll, using the separate thread is really the only way to go.  For intermediate situations...  I've never heard of writing to a pipe from a signal, but it sounds like a good compromise.

Comment: "Traditional" unix solutions to signals problems were around long before threading came to unix, let alone pthreads! The self-pipe trick is an absolute classic, being both extremely simple and avoiding all race conditions. I certainly can't write an implementation of a flag-based solution without checking the manuals and doing some brain-bending; what if the signal fires just after the check, so the main loop isn't woken up and doesn't check the flag soon? On the other hand, I can write a self-pipe solution off the top of my head and it really is race-free and robust.

Comment: @NicholasWilson If the non-signal code can go into an unbound wait, then I agree that the flag solution isn't viable; in the pre-thread days, the solution I'd always seen was to put a timeout on the select (so that the wait wasn't bound).  But as I said, when the processing is too complex for a signal handler, _and_ there's no issue about waiting until the main thread executes a `select` to do it, then the pipe sounds like a very good solution.  Setting up the signal to unblock a thread isn't trivial either.

Answer (score 3):

Except the traditional Unix way with signal handlers, there is other:

- since Linux kernel 2.6.22 there is `signalfd()` function present. You may obtain a **usual file descriptor** and poll it (using `select` or `epoll`) for incoming signals. So when you handle a signal **there is no any limitations proper to them** -- it's just usual userspace code, so you can call whatever you want...
- as far as I know for OS X, there is similar feature present in kqueue (search this site or internet for `EVFILT_SIGNAL` and `kqueue`)